# When referencing a 1GP connected app from a 2GP package, what happens when the certificate associated with the connected app is updated?

Tags: connected-apps, 2gp, 2gp-ama

Given this detail about referencing an explicit version of a connected app from a 1GP managed package to include it in a 2GP package, what are the implications of updating an expiring certificate for this connected app in the packaging org?

Will the 2GP package need any updates in order for the connected app to continue to function in subscriber orgs? Will it work seamlessly using the newly updated certificate just as 1GP packages do?

**Package Connected Apps in Second-Generation Managed Packaging**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_connected_app.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to upload a new version of the Connected App, as it is a "live" system. The only requirement is that you include the correct version so that the dependency is formed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. You will require a new version of the package to be uploaded. I have tried it, and it doesn't allow any connected app version that's not in a managed package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).